# rotate an instantiated object from an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array which I am cycling through using my arrow keys, my goal is to make the objects rotate when they are instantiated (including the first) and then when I click them using a mouse it will stop them from rotating. Unfortunately I cant seem to find a good way to get the rotation to affect my instantiated objects.

I havent written the on mouse click aspect yet, but I was planning on just using a raycast.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
// This array stores the Prefabs
public GameObject[] ObjectArray;

// Integer for stepping through array Prefabs
private int selectedObject = 0;

// Location to instantiate the prefab
public Transform locator;

// Holds the currently instantiated Prefab in the scene
public GameObject tempMesh;

void Start()
{
    // Instantiate initial Prefab
    tempMesh = Instantiate(ObjectArray[selectedObject], locator.position, locator.rotation);
}



void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {

        // Step to next position in array
        selectedObject++;

        // If Array count excedes Array index then go back to first position in array
        if (selectedObject >= ObjectArray.Length)
        {
            selectedObject = 0;
        }

        // Remove previously instantiated prefab from hierarchy
        Destroy(tempMesh);

        // Instantiated next Prefab
        tempMesh = Instantiate(ObjectArray[selectedObject], locator.position, locator.rotation);

        // Print Counter for debug
        print(selectedObject);


    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {

        // Step to next position in array
        selectedObject--;

        // If Array count excedes Array index then go back to first position in array
        if (selectedObject >= ObjectArray.Length)
        {
            selectedObject = 5;
        }
        if (selectedObject < 0)
        {
            selectedObject = 5;
        }

        // Remove previously instantiated prefab from hierarchy
        Destroy(tempMesh);

        // Instantiated next Prefab
        tempMesh = Instantiate (ObjectArray [selectedObject], locator.position, locator.rotation);

        // Print Counter for debug
        print(selectedObject);


    }
    GameObject yourObject = Instantiate (ObjectArray [Capsule], new Vector3 (0, 0, 3.0f), Quaternion.identity);

    // Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
    yourObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

}

Comment: What is it about `selectedObject = 5;`? Shouldn't it be `selectedObject = ObjectArray.Length - 1;` ?

Comment: You are losing instances of `yourObject`. Can't find a `Destroy(yourObject);` I'm didn't do any unity3d, but these are just some questions while looking at the code.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen there are 6 objects in my array, so when using the left arrow and moving below element 0 it will return you to the beginning of the array which is element 5. Not sure if this was the most efficient way but I am fairly new to c# and it worked haha. Do you think thats whats preventing the rotation from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Unity uses a Component model.

The easiest way to affect a GameObject is to attach a script to it.
Try to attach a separate 'rotate until clicked' script to the objects you are instantiating.

For the click detection a ray-cast is a good solution.

EDIT: with the further information from comments, this was tried but failed in an unusual way (the rotation was progressive).
I believe this is still the correct way to achieve the desired effect, but without the previous attempt's code I can't correct it.

The simple fix to the code as posted would be:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
// This array stores the Prefabs
public GameObject[] ObjectArray;

// Integer for stepping through array Prefabs
private int selectedObjectIndex = 0;

// Location to instantiate the prefab
public Transform locator;

// Holds the currently instantiated Prefab in the scene
public GameObject selectedObject;

void Start()
{
    // Instantiate initial Prefab
    selectedObject = Instantiate(ObjectArray[selectedObjectIndex], locator.position, locator.rotation);
}



void Update()
{
    bool objectChanged = false;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        // Step to next position in array
        selectedObjectIndex++;

        // If Array count exceeds Array index then go back to first position in array
        if (selectedObjectIndex >= ObjectArray.Length)
        {
            selectedObjectIndex= 0;
        }
    
        objectChanged = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {

        // Step to next position in array
        selectedObjectIndex--;
        // Wrap to end of list if needed
        if (selectedObjectIndex< 0)
        {
            selectedObjectIndex= ObjectArray.Length - 1;
        }
    
        objectChanged = true;
    }

    if (objectChanged)
    {
        // Remove previously instantiated prefab from hierarchy
        Destroy(selectedObject);

        // Instantiate next Prefab
        selectedObject= Instantiate(ObjectArray[selectedObjectIndex], locator.position, locator.rotation);

        // Print Counter for debug
        print(selectedObjectIndex);
    }

    // Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
    selectedObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

Comment: This was the first solution I tried, and while it technically worked, it was definitely not the desired effect. Essentially on each instance spawn it would create the object in a static position that was incrementally rotated from the last. Ideally I would like each object to maintain its rotation on spawn.

Comment: I removed that location attached to the tempMesh and the instances. I am using this very simply rotation script but unfortunately still not working                                             
                                                                                                                                               
'{
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _rotation;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
        transform.Rotate(_rotation * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}'

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a direct modification of your code which should work. NOTE: that I have left the instantiate setting the rotation to your locator.rotation, this makes it match the locator object on creation. If you don't want this, then replace it with Quaternion.identity as you were attempting in your original snippet.

Comment: Pete, thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this, it works! Now I just need to figure out the raycasting and this will be great!

Comment: @JK you don't need raycasting if you e.g. use `OnMouseDown` ;)